# How to have a button connect to multiple viewcontrollers based on a sent variable, and send a new variable

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I've tried asking this question multiple ways but haven't found any luck. It's hard to compress my problem into a single line.

Here's where I'm at:

1. viewcontroller1 sends a variable ("X" or "Y") to viewcontroller2
2. viewcontroller2 has a button.
3. if the variable sent to viewcontroller2 == "x" the button on viewcontroller2 should perform a segue to viewcontroller3, and send its .title as a variable to that view controller
4. if the variable == "y" the button on viewcontroller2 should perform a segue to viewcontroller4, and send its .title as a variable to that view controller

I can do steps 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4.

Here's where I'm at on viewcontroller2:

```
 @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if sentvar == "X" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVC3", sender: self)
    if sentvar == "Y" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVC4", sender: self)
```

Then lower in the code, I added:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier) == "ToVC3" {
         let newvar = segue.destination as! VC3
        newvar.var = (sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)!
```

But... ain't workin.
I don't understand how to combine the prepareforsegue to send a variable, and the performsegue dependent on the previously sent variable.

I'm happy to explain what I've tried and how it hasn't worked if that is helpful, but I've been stuck on this problem all day and am hoping someone with skills can point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Add the relevant sections of your code from `viewcontroller2`. These include the `UIButton`s `IBAction` and your `prepare(for:, sender:)` method and the property holding the "variable".

Comment: Your approach looks correct. What exactly is not working when you try it?

Comment: Robert: I get a  "Thread1 signal: SIGABRT" crash and an error when i press the button on viewcontroller2  saying: "Could not cast value of type 'myproject.viewcontroller2' (0x101af1ab0) to 'UIButton'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your `viewController2` store the segueIdentifier for `viewController3` and `viewController4`. Do also store a variable called `letter`. So in `viewController2`store these variables:

```
var letter = ""
var segueIdentifierThirdVC = "ToVC3"
var segueIdentifierFourthVC = "ToVC4"
```

When you segue from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` , you need to pass the above `letter` variable.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination == "ToVC1" {
        let viewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2
        viewController2.letter = // either x or y
    }
}
```

And then in your `ViewController2`, when you click the button and want to segue you just make this check:

```
func buttonClicked() {
    if letter == "x" {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifierThirdVC, sender: nil)
    } else if letter == "y" {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifierFourthVC, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the right identifiers stored.

**Update**
To set the title label in `viewController3` and `viewController4` do the following:

In `viewController3` and `viewController4` store a variable called: `var title = ""`

After you have called the function buttonClicked in `viewController2` and you have started your `performSegue` you do this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination == "ToVC3" {
        let viewController3 = segue.destination as? ViewController3
        viewController3.title = // pass title to ViewController3
    } else if segue.destination == "ToVC4" {
        let viewController4 = segue.destination as? ViewController4
        viewController4.title = // pass title to ViewController4
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have this all set, but still don't know how to send the title of the button clicked ad a variable to viewcontroller3 or 4.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get the title of the button to be passed, so I was trying to use: 
         let newvar = segue.destination as! VC3
        newvar.var = (sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)! but I get an error/crash

Comment: Try to set it in the `viewDidLoad` instead `button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)`

Comment: yep, that's where it is!

Comment: no. I get a "Thread1 signal: SIGABRT" crash and an error when i press the button on viewcontroller2 saying: "Could not cast value of type 'myproject.viewcontroller2' (0x101af1ab0) to 'UIButton'"

Comment: @tfcamp, I created the entire flow for you with a test project. Checkout how I have done it. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwmfdoq8sxgsgxd/TestSegue.zip?dl=0) is the test project.

Comment: Thanks very much. It got me much closer and I found some errors in my code based on yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

But you will need to look into a prepare for segue statement.

Please see the below code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if sender == ShowVC {
        let yourVc = segue.destination as? YourViewController
        yourVc?.YOUR_VARIABLE = VariableWithDataFromCurrentVc
    }
}
```

Can be called with

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowVC", sender: self)
```

Then you will just have to make a check on the variable, and then perform a segue to the correct VC.

Comment: Thanks. I can pass a variable from one viewcontroller to the next, but can't figure out how to do that if I also need to button to go to one of two viewcontrollers, based on a variable that has already been passed to it.

Comment: I just saw you edited your question. But why do you want to pass in the button? I'm still unsure about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question to show what code I've tried so far. I want to send the name of the button as a variable to either viewcontroller 3, or viewcontroller4. The variable x, or y (which is already sent to viewcontroller2 from viewcontroller1 specifies which viewcontroller the button will send its title to.

Comment: Please have a look here @tfcamp https://github.com/Grumme/Segue-project. I created a simple project, but I'm still unsure if it's doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks so much! Everything looks good until the viewcontroller2... from there I would want that button to go to viewcontroller3 if x was passed, or viewcontroller4 if y was passed. I would also want the button on viewcontroller2 to send its buttontitle to viewcontroller3 or 4.